# Getting errors when I import libraries used for facial recognition?

Tags: python, argparse, facial-identification

I am following this tutorial on [facial recognition](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/06/11/how-to-build-a-custom-face-recognition-dataset/?fbclid=IwAR2lV7SwfseX_EONQqmq3Brbwi09HLyZL8l9d_ukV38p1_ZcZsPcoHFaSL0). It is teaching me how to create a dataset for facial recognition.

Thus far, I am importing my libraries; however, I get the following error:

> usage: facial_recognition.py [-h] -c/ --cascade C/ __CASCADE -o OUTPUT
>   facial_recognition.py: error: the following arguments are required:
>   -c/ --cascade/-o/--output, -o/--output

This is the code that I used

```
import argparse
import imutils
import time
import cv2
import os
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-c/ --cascade", "-o/--output", required=True, 
    help = "path to where the face cascade resides")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=True,
    help="path to output directory")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

Comment: Looks like you didn't provide any command line arguments when you ran your script?

Comment: I guess you try to import a module which was only written as a standalone script.

Comment: Did you read the link about argparse? https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/03/12/python-argparse-command-line-arguments/